# TabLayout Fragments got binding NullPointerException after popBackStack (come from fragment)

Tags: kotlin, uinavigationcontroller, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2, android-viewbinding

TI have a problem with some fragments in a Single Activity App using ViewBinding, and is when i go from fragment A (which has a ViewPager2 and TabLayout with 3 fragments) to another fragment B and then go back to fragment A (pressing back button). When im back in fragment A, if i try to use any method created inside the tab fragments and using them from fragment A, it says NullPointerException on FragmentTab1.getBinding, or any of the fragments in the tabs.

Context:

*agregarMuestraFragment* (Fragment A) is a fragment with a ViewPager2 and TabLayout to display 3 Fragments inside it with tabs, and is conected (Using the settings button) to a fragment called *configuracionFragment* (Fragment B)

[image]

This is the ViewPagerAdapter

```kotlin
class ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle):
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    var fragments = mutableListOf<Fragment>()

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragments.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragments[position]
    }

    public fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        fragments.add(fragment)
    }
}
```

And in agregarMuestrasFragment i'm creating the viewpager and tab layout in onViewCreated this way.

```kotlin
viewPagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(
    childFragmentManager,
    lifecycle
)

fragmentTaxonomia = FragmentTaxonomia()
fragmentColeccion = FragmentColeccion(this@AgregarMuestrasFragment::animarConfigIcon)
fragmentLugar = FragmentLugar()

viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(
    fragmentLugar
)
viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(
    fragmentColeccion
)
viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(
    fragmentTaxonomia
)

binding.viewPager2.adapter = viewPagerAdapter

TabLayoutMediator(
    binding.tabLayout,
    binding.viewPager2
) { tab, position ->
    when (position) {
        0 -> tab.text = "Lugar"
        1 -> tab.text = "Colección"
        2 -> tab.text = "Taxonomía"
    }
}.attach()

binding.tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
        when(tab.position) {
            2 -> {
                binding.btnGeolocalizar.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.btnAgregarMuestra.isEnabled = true
            }
            1 -> {
                binding.btnGeolocalizar.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.btnAgregarMuestra.isEnabled = true
            }
            0 -> {
                binding.btnGeolocalizar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.btnAgregarMuestra.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
    }

    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
    }
})
```

The reason behind initializing the fragments that way is because i need their reference to use some functions defined inside them. Those functions change the ui of the tab fragments when i press the Geolocalizar button or Agregar muestra button in *agregarMuestrasFragment*.

```kotlin
// listener in agregarMuestrasFragment

binding.btnGeolocalizar.setOnClickListener{
    fragmentLugar.startLoadingDepartamento()
    fragmentLugar.startLoadingMunicipio()
}
```

This is the function startLoadingDepartamento in *fragmentLugar*

```kotlin
// function defined in fragmentLugar, 
// which is a tab from agregarMuestrasFragment
// This functions is called from agregarMuestrasFragment

public fun startLoadingCoordenadasDepto(){
    binding.wraperLongitud.alpha = 0.3f
    binding.wraperLatitud.alpha = 0.3f
    binding.wraperAlturaMinima.alpha = 0.3f
    binding.progressBarLatitud.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    binding.progressBarLongitud.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    binding.progressBarAlturaMinima.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

The same happend with the grey button at the bottom (Agregar muestra). When pressed, it calls some functions from the fragments to change their UI.

```kotlin
// listener in agregarMuestrasFragment

binding.btnAgregarMuestra.setOnClickListener {
    fragmentColeccion.colectorPrincipalSetError()
    fragmentLugar.setErrorAlturaMinima()
    fragmentTaxonomia.caracteristricasIndividuoRemoveError()
}
```

And this works perfectly if i dont go to *configurationFragment*. When i go from agregarMuestrasFragment to configuracionFragment and then go back to agregarMuestrasFragment , if i try to press the Geolocalizar button or Agregar Muestra button to use the functions defined inside the tab fragments, i got a NullPointerException at

```kotlin
FragmentLugar.getBinding(FragmentLugar.kt:31)
//or 
FragmentTaxonomia.getBinding(FragmentTaxonomia.kt:22)
```

and those lines of the fragments is where i define the binding variable

```kotlin
private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

Comment: You may have something like this:

`override fun onDestroyView() { super.onDestroyView();  _binding = null; }` somewhere in `FragmentLugar` and in `FragmentTaxonomia`. So when your fragments are detached from screen the `_binding` variable inside them maybe `null`. So the `NullPointerException` is raised when you try to access `_binding` with `!!` when it's value is actually `null`. Please check it, and if I'm wrong – maybe add some details to your question.

Comment: @Narmo Thats true Narmo, in each fragment from the ViewPager i have an onDestroyView where i set _binding = null.

Comment: then I suggest to rethink your architecture — your bindings will be null by the moment any of these fragments goes off-screen. Of course you may get rid of `_binding` and make `binding` variables optional, but original flaw in architecture will stay.

Comment: @Narmo hey Narmo, i changed the way i call the fragments methods from its parents. Everything is working now 